# How to assign foreign key in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle

I am try to assign foreign key in Oracle 10g. But the error shows like

ORA-907: missing right parentheses

I  have three tables

TblCustomer
TblProducts
TblSales

```
create table tblSales
(SalesID int primary key,
ProductId int foreign key references tblProducts(ProductId),
CustomerID int foreign key references tblCustomer(CustomerID),
SalesPrice numeric,
SalesDate date);
```

Whats going wrong can you suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

You syntax must look like:

```
create table tblSales (SalesID int, 
ProductId int , 
CustomerID int , 
SalesPrice numeric, 
SalesDate date,
CONSTRAINT sales_pk PRIMARY KEY (SalesID ),
CONSTRAINT fk_produkt
foreign key (ProductId)references tblProducts(ProductId),
CONSTRAINT fk_customer
foreign key (CustomerID)references tblCustomer(CustomerID)

);
```

Comment: till same problem going to face..dear

Comment: Can you proide the other 2 table create statements?

Comment: @DhavalGhevariya sorry i forgot an comma. Have added it.

Answer (score 2):

For in inline foreign key you don't specify the `foreign key` keyword:

```
create table tblSales
(
   SalesID int primary key,
   ProductId int references tblProducts(ProductId),
   CustomerID int references tblCustomer(CustomerID),
   SalesPrice numeric,
   SalesDate date
);
```

With inline foreign keys, you don't even need to specify the target column:

```
create table tblSales
(
   SalesID int primary key,
   ProductId int references tblProducts,
   CustomerID int references tblCustomer,
   SalesPrice numeric,
   SalesDate date
);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/420b9c

---

<sup>As a side note: prefixing each and every table with `tbl` doesn't really make sense. If you are programming, do you prefix every class with `Cls` or if you are naming a person, do you prefix every name with `Pers`?</sup>